# Using generics to load all json files of a type stored locally

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to construct a generic persistence routine for a personal Swift package I can use in my own projects.

The idea:

- I can feed the `save(instance:)` method and it will

  - create a new folder in the documents folder named with the name of the type of instance I pass (i.e. if I pass an instance of `Contact`, the folder will be called `Contact`
  - save the instance as json
- to load all instances of a specific type, I want to use a `loadAll(of type:)` method which

  - decodes all files within that folder if it exists
  - returns an array of these instances

Here's the packages persistence class:

```
public class ATPersistLocally {

    public static let shared = ATPersistLocally()

    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    private let fileManager: FileManager = {
        return FileManager.default
    }()

    private let docPath: URL = {
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        guard let docPath = urls.first else { fatalError() }
        ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Doc path is: \(docPath)", type: .debug)
        return docPath
    }()

    //MARK: - Loading
    public func loadAll<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T) -> [T] {
        var result = [T]()

        let typeName = getTypeName(of: type) //custom helper method, see below

        let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: typeName))
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathFolder.path) {
            var urls = [URL]()
            do {
                urls = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: pathFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            } catch let error {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not load content of directory: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }

            for url in urls {
                if let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: url.path) {
                    do {
                        let instance = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                        result.append(instance)
                    } catch let error {
                        ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not decode data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }

    //MARK: - Saving
    public func save<T: Codable & Identifiable>(instance: T) {
        let typeName = getTypeName(of: instance)

        let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: typeName))
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathFolder.absoluteString) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: pathFolder.relativePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
            } catch let error {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not create folder for type \(typeName): \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }
        }

        let path = pathFolder.appendingPathComponent(instance.id as! String)

        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(instance)
            do {
                try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path.relativePath))
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Saved instance of \(typeName)", type: .debug)
            } catch let error {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not save data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }
        } catch let error {
            ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not encode data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Helper Functions
    private func getTypeName<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T) -> T.Type {
        return T.self
    }
}
```

While this compiles and saving already works just fine, I do have a problem with loading.

Here's an example struct (which has to be `Codable & Identifiable` if I understand correctly) that I am trying to use:

```
import Foundation

struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let contactTitle: String
    var name: String? = nil
    var firstname: String? = nil
    var address: String? = nil
    var zip: String? = nil
    var city: String? = nil
}
```

And here's the load call I am trying to make:

```
var contacts = ATPersistLocally.shared.loadAll(of: Contact.self)
```

The error I am getting at build time is `Argument type 'Contact.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'`.

I also tried to call `contacts = ATPersistLocally.shared.loadAll(of: Contact)`, which results in the exact same error message.

**Clearly I am misunderstanding something concerning the generics concept here** - which is why any hint in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the parameter `type` in `loadAll` must be `T.Type`

```
public func loadAll<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T.Type) -> [T] { ...
```

This makes the method `getTypeName` obsolete because you can write

```
let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: T.self))
```

Side note:

The `error` instance is implicitly available in a `catch` block, `let error` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me into the right direction! Turns out my `save(instance:)` method had changed as well when I wrote the question – what I mean to say is that the above `save(instance:)` method does not work as is.

Hoping that it might anyone else, I post the current iteration of `ATPersistLocally` including your solution as an answer here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I already accepted vadian's answer as the correct answer, so all the credit's go to him.

I also want to provide the whole `ATPersistLocally` class that is working for me now, hoping that it might help others as well:

```
import Foundation

public class ATPersistLocally {

    public static let shared = ATPersistLocally()

    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    private let fileManager: FileManager = {
        return FileManager.default
    }()

    private let docPath: URL = {
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        guard let docPath = urls.first else { fatalError() }
        ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Doc path is: \(docPath)", type: .debug)
        return docPath
    }()

    //MARK: - Loading
    public func loadAll<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var result = [T]()

        let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: type))
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathFolder.path) {
            var urls = [URL]()
            do {
                urls = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: pathFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            } catch {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not load content of directory: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }

            for url in urls {
                if let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: url.path) {
                    do {
                        let instance = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                        result.append(instance)
                    } catch {
                        ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not decode data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    //MARK: - Saving
    public func save<T: Codable & Identifiable>(instance: T) {
        let typeName = getTypeName(of: instance)

        let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: typeName))
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathFolder.absoluteString) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: pathFolder.relativePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
            } catch {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not create folder for type \(typeName): \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }
        }

        let path = pathFolder.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: instance.id))

        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(instance)
            do {
                try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path.relativePath))
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Saved instance of \(typeName)", type: .debug)
            } catch {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not save data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }
        } catch let error {
            ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not encode data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Helper Functions
    private func getTypeName<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T) -> T.Type {
        return T.self
    }
}
```

In projects where I want to use this logic, I import my package through SPM and make sure the struct to save / load conforms `Codable` and `Identifiable`.

> Be aware that `Identifiable` requires iOS13 as it was added to the standard library only with Swift 5.1.